# Incrementing a constant pointer variable works in a for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void display(const int* start, const int* end);

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    display(numbers, numbers + 9);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void display(const int* start, const int* end)
{
    const int* ptr;
    for (ptr = start; ptr != end; ptr++)
    {
        cout << *ptr << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is correct and works as I expected to work. 
But in the display function, I have specifically mentioned that my "ptr" variable is a constant which means that the value of the "ptr" variable cannot change and hence, it will only refer to one address at all times.

Looking at the for loop, I am able to increment the ptr variable (Why?).

So, out of curiosity I removed the const keyword from `const int* ptr` line to see what happens and it gives me the following error:

```
for (ptr = start; ptr != end; ptr++) // a value of type "const int*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"
{
    cout << *ptr << endl;
}
```

The error is for `ptr = start;`
That gave me new questions:

1. My ptr variable after modifications is NOT a const int* so why is it saying that it is a const int *?
2. I am assigning my start variable (const int *) to a ptr variable (const int *), but it thinks that I am trying to assign my start variable of type int* to a const int* which is the ptr variable?
3. Even if this does not work, then why does incrementing work when my ptr was constant before?

I looked at the following two links to understand it further but it does not answer my question:
 1. [Why this Error: a value of type "const int*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int*"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542470/why-this-error-a-value-of-type-const-int-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of) 
2. [How pointer increment works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427913/how-pointer-increment-works)

EDIT
The reason why my question is not the duplicate of this link (1. [Why this Error: a value of type "const int*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int*"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542470/why-this-error-a-value-of-type-const-int-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of)) is because this is what he is assigning a constant pointer's value to another pointer which is also pointing to another non constant value and hence why. In my case I initialized a constant integer pointer and I am still able to increment it. I do not think that we can increment constant variables?

Comment: `const int * p` is a non constant pointer to a constant `int`. Does this not answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542470/why-this-error-a-value-of-type-const-int-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why this Error: a value of type "const int\*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int\*"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542470/why-this-error-a-value-of-type-const-int-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of)

Comment: No, because const int *p is pointing to a pointer that is further pointing to a non-constant. In my case I am not doing that. I am  using a constant integer pointer to initialize it to a constant integer pointer. Then I am incrementing it the constant integer pointer. How can you increment a constant integer pointer?

Comment: The type you seem to think you have - const pointer to `int` - is spelled `int * const`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I still shouldnt be able to increment the pointer because it is "constant"

Comment: 1) is exactly what the first Q&A you link is about 2) is a bit confusing. Please post a complete example of the code you have questions about. Please do not post code, describe what you changed and ask about that modified code

Comment: the pointer is not constant. `const int * p` points to a `const int`, but `p` is not constant

Comment: @ProgrammingRage As has been said repeatedly in these comments, the pointer is *not* constant. The `int` that it points to is. Try `*ptr += 1;` and see what happens. Then change your prorotype to `void display(int* const start, int* const end)` and test that.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 so you are saying that when I say 'const int *p' it is basically expecting a constant value and it is not a constant itself?

Comment: You are confusing a `pointer to const int` with a `const pointer to int`.

Comment: yes thats what I am saying. `const int * p` is not constant. You can modify it as much as you like. Though it does point to a constant `int`, and you cannot modify the `int` through `p`

Comment: Pointers are so confusing :) But I get this! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise.   You're assuming that `const int *p` is a `const` pointer to an `int`  (i.e. the value of the pointer can't change).   Whereas it is a pointer to a `const int`  (i.e. what it points to cannot change).   So `p` can be changed (so it points at another `int`) but it can't be used to change its pointee.   This means `p++` is valid, but `*p = 42` is not.